# listview if checked select in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I want to filter the datagrid with check item in listview

[image: datatable]

Here is my code

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In listView1.CheckedItems
    con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(" WHERE A.DocNum in (@d5) AND A.DocDate Between @d1 AND @d2 AND A.CANCELED <> 'Y' AND A.SlpCode = @d3  ", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "Date").Value = dtpDateFrom.Value.Date
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "Date").Value = dtpDateTo.Value.Date
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", (item).SubItems(0).Text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of query for each check item from list view. Build the result into a formatted string from the collection. Then only perform the query. You could try replace @d5 value with the collectionList.

```
 Dim Collection As New List(Of String)

    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
        Collection.Add(Item.SubItems(0).Text)
    Next

    Dim CollectionList As String = String.Join(",", Collection.ToArray)
```

Do let me know whether it is working.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if the ode is working